# Make all possible sequences from n-gram set

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, n-gram

I know how to generate a sentences to n-gram.
Ex: unigram and bigram (using number sequence)

```
1 2 3 4 5 (original senctence)
=>
1,2,3,4,5 (unigram)
12,23,34,45 (bigram)
```

How to combine unigram and bigram (or greater n-gram) to make all possible sentences with same original length.

```
1,2,3,4,5 (unigram)
12,23,34,45 (bigram)
=> 
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 45
1 2 34 5
1 23 4 5
1 23 45
12 3 4 5
12 3 45
12 34 5
```

I want to find algorithm to solve this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: recursion - at each step either output 1 or 2 words (eg: 1 or 12). when finished, backtrack / remember old state. that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the tip:

- Assuming you have 5 numbers [1 2 3 4 5]
- There are 4 places to insert space [1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5]
- 4-digit binary number represents combination (0 - no space, 1 - space)
- For example: code 0110 matches [1 (0) 2 (1) 3 (1) 4 (0) 5] == [12 3 45]
- Iterate through all n-1 binary codes.

Comment: How would 0000 give a partition into unigrams and bigrams?

Comment: @user2566092 0000 means [12345]. This solution iterates through all possible ngrams as OP requested: "how to combine unigram and bigram (or greater n-gram)". If you need only upto bigram, filter out codes contain two and more zeros in a row